# Calling Statement for Year in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am in an Oracle Database class and this question is stumping me any help would be much appreciated !

List the art name, the price, and the new price.  The new price is 5 % greater than the old price if the art was acquired in the year 2010 and 10% greater than the old price date of acquisition is earlier than 2010.

Heres what I have tried:

```
Select ArtName,price,
CASE 
  WHEN YEAR(DtAcquired) = 2010 THEN (price*.05)+price
  WHEN YEAR(DtAcquired) < 2010 THEN(price*.10)+price 
  Else price
END as NewPrice
from arnadod_Arts;
```

But found out YEAR is an invalid identifier.

Comment: How about `extract(year from DtAcquired)`

Comment: Make sure your `DtAcquired` is a valid date format too.

Comment: to_char(DtAcquired,'YYYY') is also valid. provided, DtAcquired is a date/

Answer (score 1):

`YEAR` is MS-SQL function that also appears in few other DBMS.

In oracle you can use `TO_CHAR()` function. For example:

`TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy')` to get year number of of the date.

`TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm')` to get 2 digit month.

Full documentation on `TO_CHAR` can be found @ http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

If you want to then convert it to number just wrap it in `TO_NUMBER` like so
`TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy'))`

Answer (score 1):

If `DtAcquired` is of `Date` datatype, you can use something like:

```
SELECT ...
   CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DtAcquired) = 2010
        THEN ...
        ELSE ... END as NewPrice
```

Otherwise (for example `VARCHAR2` datatype):

```
SELECT ...
   CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(DtAcquired, 'YYYYMMDD')) = 2010
        THEN ...
        ELSE ... END as NewPrice
```